# How to Suppress Karate Failed Features Logs

Tags: java, karate

I am using GitLab to run a set of Karate feature files in the pipeline but it is throwing a Java Heap Space error before the execution is completed. I suspect that it may have to do with all of the failed features log messages that are returned when running a large set of feature files because this error doesn't occur when running the pipeline with a smaller set of feature files. I have tried running it after updating the Karate version to 1.1.0 and the Java version to 11 since these both have included fixes to some of the memory issues but I still see this issue.

Is there a way to suppress these failed feature log messages that are returned after the test execution (as referenced below) to help prevent the Java Heap Space issue especially when running a large set of feature files in the pipeline?

```
>>> failed features:
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal (STRING:STRING)
  'The dog chased the cat.'
  'The dog chased the bird.'
```

Comment: highly unlikely that the "failed feature log messages" is the issue. short answer is no, and you are welcome to contribute code to "fix" anything. the linked q & a gives you info on how to write your own report